# Copy entire excel row and paste to the bottom of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing an Excel Macro that goes through an Excel table row by row and is supposed to copy an entire row and paste it under the last row when a condition is met. Looping through the rows and meeting the condition is all working but I'm stuck on copying an certain row and pasting it to the end of the table.

```
Sub Makro1()
    Application.Goto Reference:="Makro1"

    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        'for looping
        totalRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'index of last row even after rows have been added
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    

        'data starts at row #3
        For i = 3 To totalRows
            If Cells(i, 19).Value > 0 Then
                number = Cells(i, 19).Value
                Do While number > 0
                    lastRow = lasRow + 1        
                    Rows(lastRow) = Rows(i).Value                
                    number = number - 1
                Loop
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I get runtime error 1004.
I know the nested loops are terrible, I simply need this for work (non-coding) to make my life easier.

Comment: You're using `With`, but then stop using the anchors. In your `For` loop, add `.` before all `Cells()` and `Rows()`.

Comment: Also, what line does the error throw on?

Comment: I've removed 'Application.Goto Reference:="Makro1"' which fixes the error. The question has been updated with my latest code. Now nothing happens, no error and no pasting. Any idea why?

Comment: That is a different question. Please stay on the original question, and if the answer solves *that* question, it would be good to mark it as accepted. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

... occurs on the first line of your code:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="Makro1"
```

That statement expects a named range with name "Makro1", but cannot find it. If it would have found it, the range would have scrolled into view. If this is not important to you, then just comment that line out:

```
' Application.Goto Reference:="Makro1"
```

Otherwise, open the "Names Manager" from the "Formulas" tab on the ribbon, and check the named ranges your Workbook has. Possibly recreate "Makro1" if you know which range was supposed to be called that way.

Comment: Thanks, the error message is gone. Unfortunately nothing is happening though (no rows are being pasted). You have any idea why it doesn't? I've updated the post with the code I have now.

Comment: Please restore your question with the original problem, because now my answer makes no sense anymore. Please don't change your questions like that; you can always ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't think of that. Restored the question.

Comment: Perfect, I see you posted the new question as well, and are already getting answers :)